# Console Console Api - Local Redirect Url

Tags: api, url, console, local

I want to register a new client id in the Google APIs Console where the redirect url is in local but when I type it it says my url is invalid.

The local url I want to add is something like :
"http://whatever.something.somethingelse/projectfolder"

Is there a way to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been googling for hours on this issue. Can't figure out how to set some local domain callback url while I'm in developing mode.

It seems that it's not possible. I'm hope I'm wrong.